# Why custom Axis2 version in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, apache-axis

Well, when developing custom transports for WSO2 ESB I was recommended to use Axis2 version specific to WSO2 (1.6.1-wso2v5). Does anybody know if this version somehow differs from the "standard" 1.6.1 version? And what was the motivation for this "branching"?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this was because some changes were done that was needed for wso2 specific details. Hence a separate wso2 version was created to cater this need.

Comment: Do you exactly know what were those "details" and is it crucial to use wso2 specific version or axis2 base version is just enough?

Comment: nope, sorry i am not aware of the exact details i think there are several changes that have been done. i assume you would run into errors if you use the axis2 base version but cannot tell you with 100% certainty how that will work out.