# WSO2 IS Samples uses artifacts not from maven repositories

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to import the [a OAuth2 sample](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/4.7.0/modules/samples/oauth2/playground2) from the [a WSO2 IS doc](https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/OAuth+2.0+Playground+with+WSO2+Identity+Server) and found that a lot of dependencies are from the WEB-INF/lib and with versions that seems to be mangled  by the WSO2 people. For example, the pom.xml contains dependency declarations like:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.wso2v2</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.6.0.wso2v2.jar</systemPath> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.gdata.wso2</groupId>
         <artifactId>gdata-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.wso2v1</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/gdata-core-1.0.0.wso2v1.jar</systemPath> 
    </dependency>
```

And so on. I don't find any motivation for that: why not using public libraries? Are they patched? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they made some adjustments to some libraries in order to adapt them to the wso2 stack and its particular features and requirements. You can just see it as the same library, with a few refinements to work better in wso2 related projects.

see also [Why custom Axis2 version in WSO2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675753/why-custom-axis2-version-in-wso2)

Comment: Thanks: I see that i'm not alone in wondering why that happens :)